# Avoiding dynamic_cast for downcasting to the original type

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

How can I downcast safely (ie returning null on failure) to the exact type of the underlying object, without incurring the performance penalty of `dynamic_cast`, and without having to put support code in every class I use?

Comment: If that were possible, then why would `dynamic_cast` not implement this method?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `dynamic_cast` is strictly more powerful. This is essentially a special use case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: He modified the question.

Comment: I don’t understand how this makes a difference but I’ll assume for now that I’m just overlooking something. Maybe I’m just not understanding “the exact type of the underlying object” correctly. An example code would be useful of the requested semantics (and, more importantly, what it *needn’t* be able to do) would be helpful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this is only for use when you need to convert from a base pointer to the exact same type the underlying object actually is (i.e. not any intermediary classes).

Comment: Have you measured the cost of dynamic_cast when the operand is of exactly the right type?

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes, it's in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` will traverse the entire inheritance tree to see if the conversion you want is possible. If all you want is a direct downcast to the *same* type as the object, and you don't need the ability to cross cast, to cast across virtual inheritance, or to cast to a base class of the object's actual type, the following code will work:

```
template<class To>
struct exact_cast
{
    To result;

    template<class From>
    exact_cast(From* from)
    {
        if (typeid(typename std::remove_pointer<To>::type) == typeid(*from))
            result = static_cast<To>(from);
        else
            result = 0;
    }

    operator To() const
    {
        return result;
    }
};
```

The semantics are exactly the same as for other cast operators, ie

```
Base* b = new Derived();
Derived* d = exact_cast<Derived*>(b);
```

**Edit:** I have tested this on a project I am working on. My results from `QueryPerformanceCounter` are:
`dynamic_cast`: 83,024,197
`exact_cast`:78,366,879
Which is a 5.6% speedup. This is for non-trivial CPU-bound code. (It does no I/O)

Comment: Any evidence that this is any more efficient than a `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Also, why a class instead of a function?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I would not be surprised if it was more efficient (getting the `typeinfo` should just be a few dereferences away, no big computation involved).

Comment: This code appeared to be .05 of a second faster against `dynamic_cast` in my test for 4,000,000 iterations of constructing a polymorphic object on the heap and assigning to a base pointer, casting to derived, and deallocating it (with `-Ofast` optimisation level on gcc 4.7.1).

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: I misunderstood the code. I removed the comment.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: This is probably what OP meant by "all you want is a direct downcast to the *same* type as the object". That "same" is supposed to mean that you are allowed to downcast to the *most derived object type* only, not to intermediate bases. This, of course, greatly limits the usability of this cast.

Comment: @AndreyT That is what I meant. I will clarify that.

Comment: @NicolBolas That is true. I have update the question to what I meant to say.