# Decoupling exceptions from log formatting

Tags: c++, exception

In my API I have a small exception hierarchy, derived from `std::exception`. I have a base class `Exception`, which provides an error code, file, line, and function. Other more specific exceptions are derived from `Exception`. For example, one derived class adds a platform-specific error code, as well as a field that identifies which function returned the error code. This is like a simplified version of `system_error`, but I can't use C++11 features (I'm stuck working with VS2005, and no Boost).

I need to log these exceptions with my logging class. I want the exceptions to be logged in a certain format. After reading various forums online, and reading [Boost's Error and Exception Handling Guidelines](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html), I don't think the `what` function of each exception, or any other virtual function within `Exception`, is the appropriate place to format the exception for logging. Therefore my `what` functions just return the name of the class.

When catching exceptions, I often want to catch very general exceptions, usually `std::exception`, and pass it to the logger. I don't want to catch individual exceptions very often because I am trying to prevent exceptions from escaping the API (the public portion of my API is in C), and there may be several exceptions that could occur. I want to avoid code like:

```
try { /* blah */ }
catch {DerivedException const& ex) { logger.log(ex); }
...
catch {Exception const& ex) { logger.log(ex); }
```

So in my logging class, my `log` function accepts a `std::exception` argument. It then uses `typeid` to compare the parameter to the various exception classes, casting to the appropriate type and then calling a logging function specialized for that type of exception. This is essentially the same technique described [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494524/avoiding-dynamic-cast-for-downcasting-to-the-original-type).

I use `typeid` instead of `dynamic_cast` because `dynamic_cast` can succeed for any valid downcast, and for code maintenance purposes, I really don't want the order of my `if` statements in the `log` function to matter.

So is this a decent design? It feels wrong to me using `typeid` like this, but I think I have valid reasons to do it. I haven't seen much exception handling "in the wild", since we primarily work with C, so I haven't seen too many approaches to the subject. Are there other ways to decouple exceptions from their log formatting that I should be aware of?

**EDIT: What I decided to implement**
I took the suggestion of using the visitor pattern, but adapted it to my situation. I wanted to catch `std::exception`, since those can be thrown as well as my own, but format the log message based on the exception type.

Each of my exception classes derive from my base `Exception` class and implement the virtual function `accept`. I created an `ExceptionLogger` class, which implements an `ExceptionVisitor` interface providing the `visit` functions.

The `LogFile` class has an instance of `ExceptionLogger`, as well as an overload of its `log` function that takes an `std::exception` parameter. In the `log` function, I try a `dynamic_cast` to my base type, `Exception`. If it succeeds, I call the `accept` function of the exception, otherwise I call the `ExceptionLogger::visit(std::exception const&)` function directly. Since `std::exception` doesn't implement my `accept` function, I needed the `dynamic_cast` so I could determine if more detailed logging was possible.

I chose to do this instead of a series of `if` statements checking `typeid` because:

1. It's a named design pattern that I can refer future maintainers to
2. If a maintainer adds a new exception deriving from my `Exception` base, but forgets to implement a new `visit` function for that exception, I will still get the logging that was implemented for the base `Exception` - a file, line number, and function.

   If I had implemented the series of `if` statements, I would've had to fall back to the `std::exception` logging behavior, which is just to print out the results of `what`, or I could've tried a `dynamic_cast` to an `Exception`.

   Of course I would still prefer a compiler error in this situation.

Comment: The alternative would be to apply the Visitor pattern.

Comment: @DDrmmr - I ended up using the Visitor pattern. Make this an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution is to rethrow your exception in your central formatting method (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387667/5379211)). You can then catch each exception type there and format it.

```
class Exception : public std::exception {};
class DerivedException : public Exception {};
void LogThrownException();

void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        // Do something, might throw ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LogThrownException();
    }
}

void LogThrownException()
{
    try
    {
        throw;
    }
    // Order is important to catch all derived types.
    // Luckily the compiler should warn, if a type is hidden.
    catch (DerivedException&)
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedException";
    }
    catch (Exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception";
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "std::exception";
    }
    // ...
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: other answer you mention could be deleted any time, so, describe here sthing

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I edited my answer. I'm new here and thought it's maybe better not to duplicate.

Comment: That is a much simpler solution. Unfortunately it's too late to implement it, but I like it and will keep it in mind for the future.